# C# Postback - set text on page after sending download

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, response, postback

I have a form that on submit, downloads a generated csv file. I have an asp:Literal on the page as a placeholder for loading text:

```
<div id="loading-text">
    <asp:Literal ID="litLoadingText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</div>
```

---

```
$("input[type=submit]").on("click", function() {
    //$(".loading-modal").show();
    $("#loading-text").html("Loading...");
});
```

and I'm trying to change the text after the download is complete to say "Done!" or just get removed:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
var fileName = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFileName.Value) ? txtFileName.Value : "ContentExport";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}.xls", fileName));
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();

    litLoadingText.Text = "Done!";
}
```

but the text doesn't change. I'm pretty sure this is because of the downloading, where I'm doing Response.End() and whatnot, but I'm not sure how to handle it. Is there a way to do this in C#, or is there a Javascript method I could use instead to detect when the download is done? What would be the best approach?

Comment: Did you try adding text to your asp:literal before flushing/ending the response?

Comment: Are you sure the excel file is downloaded successfully?

Comment: Are you sure the literal still exists after doing `$("#loading-text").html("Loading...");`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is described here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/312629/prb-threadabortexception-occurs-if-you-use-response-end-response-redir

## Cause

The Response.End method ends the page execution and shifts the execution to the Application_EndRequest event in the application's event pipeline. The line of code that follows Response.End is not executed.

This problem occurs in the Response.Redirect and Server.Transfer methods because both methods call Response.End internally.

## Resolution

To work around this problem, use one of the following methods:

For Response.End, call the HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest method instead of Response.End to bypass the code execution to the Application_EndRequest event.

For Response.Redirect, use an overload, Response.Redirect(String url, bool endResponse) that passes false for the endResponse parameter to suppress the internal call to Response.End. For example:

```
Response.Redirect ("nextpage.aspx", false);
```

If you use this workaround, the code that follows Response.Redirect is executed.

For Server.Transfer, use the Server.Executemethod instead.